# I do not receive a prompt for payment when clicking "Finish" after signing. What are the requirements for creating a payment tab with the Rest API?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the C# SDK. I see there are some examples in some other questions on here but they appear to be outdated (for example, Number no longer has a PaymentItemCode property in the SDK, and some examples don't even include a number tab at all). I've also looked at the example in the GIT repo (C# launcher), but it isn't clear what exactly the minimum required fields to request a payment for a fixed payment amount are. We're not using a template - we are building the PDF dynamically and sending it over to DocuSign in the CreateEnvelope() request, followed by the CreateRecipientView(), then presenting them with the signing ceremony via the CreateRecipientView() request. All other tabs are working fine. With the payment, I see the amount showing up on the PDF but I do not get prompted for payment when I click "Finish". Here is the relevant code that I have.. Thanks in advance.

```
        PaymentLineItem paymentLineIteml1 = new PaymentLineItem
        {
            Name = "Application Fee",
            Description = "Application Fee",
            AmountReference = "Application Fee"
            // This seems like it should reference something?
        };

        PaymentDetails paymentDetails = new PaymentDetails
        {
            GatewayAccountId = "OUR_GATEWAY_ACCOUNT_ID",
            CurrencyCode = "USD",
            GatewayName = "OUR_GATEWAY_NAME",
            GatewayDisplayName = "OUR_GATEWAY_DISPLAY_NAME",
            LineItems = new List<PaymentLineItem> { paymentLineIteml1 }
        };

        FormulaTab paymentFormula = new FormulaTab
        {
            Value = "35",
            PaymentDetails = paymentDetails,
            AnchorString = "Signature:",
            AnchorYOffset = "30",
            AnchorUnits = "pixels",
            AnchorXOffset = "180",
            TabLabel = "Application Fee",
            Required = "true",
            RecipientId = "1",
            Formula = "35"
        };

        Tabs signer1Tabs = new Tabs
        {
            FormulaTabs = new List<FormulaTab> { paymentFormula }
        };
```

**EDIT**: I was almost there. At least one line item is required, and in order to get that line item to show up, it must reference another formula tab (via the "AmountReference" property, which should actually reference the "TabLabel" property of the formula tab). In other words, the most basic way to collect a payment is with 2 formula tabs - one to represent a single line item, and one to represent the total payment amount. Otherwise, you will not be prompted for a payment when clicking "Finish".

Comment: Did you set up a payment gateway? and OUR_GATEWAY_ACCOUNT_ID is the GUID for that gateway?

Comment: Hi, Inbar. Yes, we have a payment gateway set up. We have been using a template with a drag-and-drop payment tab and it's working fine, but we're moving from a template to passing in a PDF to the CreateEnvelope() call. So, assuming everything is configured correctly in DocuSign, does the code look correct?

Comment: Were you able to take a look at this by any chance, Inbar? I'm still having issues. I have also tried using a number tab, but I then receive a message stating "LEGACY_PAYMENT_DEPRECATED". Basically I just need to know, when using the C# SDK, which objects and object properties are required and which tabs need to be sent over along with the signer to prompt the user for a payment w/ a fixed amount? Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/eSignature/Examples/CollectPaymentInEnvelope.cs can you try this code?

Comment: It's working, now. It seems that a line item must reference a formula tab via the "AmountReference" property, which actually refers to the "TabLabel" property of the formula tab, and there must be at least one line item. Then there must be another formula tab that represents the total payment amount which contains the payment details which references the line item. In other words, I needed to add an additional formula tab to represent a line item. Thanks again, Inbar. If you want to add an answer to this question I'll accept it.

Comment: Just added an answer. Happy to help.

Comment: Inbar - just ran into something quite odd. It seems that if you use an anchor, with relative (AnchorXOffset and AnchorYOffset) positioning with the payment formula tabs, it breaks and the tab is no longer recognized as a payment tab and does not prompt for payment. Can you confirm that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add another FormulaTab with the TabLabel you refer to in order to make a payment.
You can find a [working C# code][1] example on GitHub.

[1]: https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/eSignature/Examples/CollectPaymentInEnvelope.cs Here is the relevant code:

```
        FormulaTab formulal1e = new FormulaTab
        {
            Font = "helvetica",
            FontSize = "size11",
            AnchorString = "/l1e/",
            AnchorYOffset = "-8",
            AnchorUnits = "pixels",
            AnchorXOffset = "105",
            TabLabel = "l1e",
            Formula = $"[l1q] * {l1Price}",
            RoundDecimalPlaces = "0",
            Required = "true",
            Locked = "true",
            DisableAutoSize = "false",
        },
        formulal2e = new FormulaTab
        {
            Font = "helvetica",
            FontSize = "size11",
            AnchorString = "/l2e/",
            AnchorYOffset = "-8",
            AnchorUnits = "pixels",
            AnchorXOffset = "105",
            TabLabel = "l2e",
            Formula = $"[l2q] * {l2Price}",
            RoundDecimalPlaces = "0",
            Required = "true",
            Locked = "true",
            DisableAutoSize = "false",
        },
        // Formula for the total 
        formulal3t = new FormulaTab
        {
            Font = "helvetica",
            Bold = "true",
            FontSize = "size12",
            AnchorString = "/l3t/",
            AnchorYOffset = "-8",
            AnchorUnits = "pixels",
            AnchorXOffset = "50",
            TabLabel = "l3t",
            Formula = $"[l1e] + [l2e]",
            RoundDecimalPlaces = "0",
            Required = "true",
            Locked = "true",
            DisableAutoSize = "false",
        };

        // Hidden formula for the payment itself
        FormulaTab formulaPayment = new FormulaTab
        {
            TabLabel = "payment",
            Formula = $"([l1e] + [l2e]) * {currencyMultiplier}",
            RoundDecimalPlaces = "0",
            PaymentDetails = paymentDetails,
            Hidden = "true",
            Required = "true",
            Locked = "true",
            DocumentId = "1",
            PageNumber = "1",
            XPosition = "0",
            YPosition = "0"
        };

        // Tabs are set per recipient / signer
        Tabs signer1Tabs = new Tabs
        {
            SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere> { signHere1 },
            ListTabs = new List<List> { listl1q, listl2q },
            FormulaTabs = new List<FormulaTab> { formulal1e, formulal2e, formulal3t, formulaPayment }
        };
        signer1.Tabs = signer1Tabs;
```

Comment: I just wanted to add, here - the formula tab does not have to actually use a formula - you can specify a fixed value by using the "Value" property.